# Sending emails from local host - Play Framework

Tags: java, email, smtp, playframework

Does anybody know the `smtp` settings that need to be applied within the `application.conf` file of a Play Framework project for sending emails on localhost?

During my unit testing I am getting the error:

> A play.exceptions.MailException has been caught, Cannot send email

The developers at Play have made sending emails so easy that the only way I could be messing up is with my settings in the config file.

I have tried just using:

```
mail.smtp=mock
```

And I tried commenting out the line above and using:

```
mail.smtp.host=127.0.0.1
```

Neither of these two approaches work. I understand that this is probably a very noob question, but I have never really dealt with setting up emails before - so I am grateful for any help that can be contributed.

If it is the case that I am unable to send email as Play would not work as an SMTP server, is there any way that I can use `mail.smtp=mock` to 'mock send' an email and allow my tests to pass?

**Useful Link**

[This is a link to the Play documentation for sending emails](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/emails#smtp)

Comment: I would think that you would need to have a mail server setup on your local machine to accept the email. You could use `@example.com` so that your mail does not go anywhere.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - Thanks for the advice. I will look into setting up a mail server on my local machine (it will no doubt come in handy)... but I would like to see if it is possible to 'mock send' emails for test purposes.

Comment: If I knew for sure it wasn't possible, I would have posted an answer; it's just my thought it's not. My guess is there's a way to black hole your emails, or use some other intercept method. I too would like to know, but that was why it was a comment and not an answer. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To better diagnose the problem, you can use the following setting (in application.conf) to give more details of the email sending process.

```
mail.debug=true
```

However, for testing purposes, I have found using GMail the easiest method for sending emails.
The configuration (again in application.conf) is...

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.user=yourGmailLogin
mail.smtp.pass=yourGmailPassword
mail.smtp.channel=ssl
```

For full details of all the configurations, the Play Framework page has lots of information on how to do this.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/emails

Comment: +1 Thanks - that is a really good work around. I don't suppose you know the purpose of `mail.smtp=mock`? I thought this may have been a way of 'mock sending' emails.

Comment: It is. Mock simply outputs the email to the console, rather than sending it through to an SMTP client. You don't get to see the output though, other than reading it in the console. So for automated test purposes, its not helpful, but for dev purposes, it shows your email generation is working, without swamping your email client with test emails during the Dev phase.

Comment: Ok, well in that case it is definately my code that is wrong. I am also still getting the `cannot send email` error even when I use gmail. It is prob just a tired brain error so I'll have a look tomorrow and maybe open a new question. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm finding that it ignores the "mock" settign anyway and just cracks on with using whatever you supply for setHostName on the SimpleEmail object.  I'd love for mock smtp to actually work

Comment: Ok, never mind, I fixed it. I was calling the .send() message on the simplemail object itself rather than import play.libs.mail and doing Mail.send(email).  Mock SMTP works a treat now.

Comment: @Codemwnci, the mock mailer can be used for automation. Just call `Mail.Mock.getLastMessageReceivedBy(emailAddress)` after you send the email and you can inspect the email that was sent.

Answer (score 1):

I use 1.2.4. (haven't ported yet...)

There are various reasons why play.mvc.Mailer.send() may fail, however the true reason is suppressed if you look at the first level of the exception thrown since what gets thrown is (play.mvc.Mailer.java:349):

```
throw new MailException("Cannot send email", ex);
```

play.exceptions.MailException inherits from java.lang.RuntimeException. The real exception, ex, is set as the cause.

I'd recommend taking a look at the cause field. Example:

```
try {
    Future<Boolean> future = play.mvc.Mailer.send(...);
} catch(MailException me) {
    System.out.println(me.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

This may print out something more useful.

Answer (score 1):

For future developers I use Play2.1 on Mac OSX, this is my mail configuration to send to localhost...

```
 host=localhost
 port=1025
 user="root@localhost" 
 from="root@localhost"
```

using MockSMTP application available at the Mac store http://mocksmtpapp.com/

Also using typesafe plugin

https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer

I hope this can help someone in the future.